# llvm basic block tracing

Tags: debugging, llvm, trace

I'm trying to navigate the LLVM toolchain (it seems to be under constant flux) and am looking for a debugging tool: I want a stream of basic blocks an LLVM program runs through as it executes. It looks like `lli` used to have a `-trace` option which did this but 2.8 doesn't seem to have this -- I am assuming there is a more 'modern' way to do this now? Would one of the `-print-after` options do what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't find a direct answer, but here is a way using valgrind:

`valgrind --log-file=blocks --vex-guest-chase-thresh=0 --trace-superblocks=yes --tool=lackey  ./a.out`

(then check the 'blocks' file)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a class that would extend the `Interpreter` class and override the `visitXXX` you need. Please note that those methods are not virtual inside the `Interpreter` so remember to update the code :)